# How to insert a code snippet from a visual studio extension

Tags: c#, razor, code-snippets, visual-studio-extensions

I am writing an extension for our group that creates a few folders and .cshtml files. This extension will also add a few dozen code snippets. I would really like to add some of the code snippets to the files when they are created so if a user changes their snippet it will also change in the generated code.  Is there any way to access/insert code snippets from an extension?

Comment: Is your issue solved?

Answer (score 0):

The code snippet is usually added when developing/writing codes. Looks like you want to make this process automatically, like the newly created/inserted file has already included the related codes. And it seems you also want to make the snippet changeable.

I’m not sure if your requirements are more related to the project template or the more complex Visual Studio extension. I can share you a simple sample about how to insert a normal code snippet from a normal VS extension to the developed project/file, but it is manually. So perhaps it’s not what you want but I hope this could give you **some references** or **a little help**.

**Sample**

**1).** Install related VS SDK, and workload for creating Visual Studio Extension project. Create a VSIX project in VS.

**2).** Right-click the project in Solution Explorer and add one new folder(named it for example Snippets), after that add a subfolder named like `My snippets`(you can add other subfolders to classify), in this subfolder add some `.snippet` files.

[image]

**3).** Edit the `.snippet` files and add some related XML codes in it. Refer to this document: [Snippet template](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/walkthrough-creating-a-code-snippet?view=vs-2019#snippet-template).

**4).** Create a new file named `XXXX.pkgdef` and save it in project root folder, edit it and add related codes in it for registering. For example(for C#)

```
[$RootKey$\Languages\CodeExpansions\CSharp\Paths]
"MySnippets"="$PackageFolder$\Snippets\XXXXXXXX"
```

**5).** Right-click the `source.extension.vsixmanaifest` file > View Designer > Asserts > if there is a source, select it and click `Edit` > Choose related things:

[image]

**6).** (Optional) Edit the `source.extension.vsixmanaifest` file > Metadata to fill the related information that you want to set, such as `Description`, `License` `Tags`…

**7).** Hit F5 to debug and an Experimental instance of VS will launch, check the code snippet feature there.

Related documents threads/blog: [Shipping Visual Studio snippets in an extension](https://www.madskristensen.net/blog/shipping-visual-studio-snippets-in-an-extension).